# Should documentation for advanced features not be approved because the basic features included in it have not been documented?

Tags: discussion, documentation

I am writing documentation for CSS selectors in Protractor and the comment came up that the basics that build up to the selectors have not been documented yet. Should we first write out the documentation for basic features (e.g. how to find a class with a CSS selector) or is it okay to document what you feel like documenting (and the commenters can just step up and document the basics). Should this documentation not be approved because the basics that build up to it have not been documented leaving a new user confused?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Should this documentation not be approved because the basics that build up to it have not been documented leaving a new user confused?

Docs isn't a step-by-step 'how to' guide for people to learn a new programming language so there is no requirement for a logical reading order as such. If what you have submitted is concise and factually correct then there is no reason for it not to be approved.

If you feel the basics *should* be there, then you have two options:

- Go and create the topic with the basics
- Request for the topic to be created

Once the basics have been documented, there is no reason that your example cannot be updated to include a link to the basics.